# Is there a world of warcraft API to help me with my guild website (loot tooltips and latest loot)?

Tags: php, database, world-of-warcraft

I'm at a loss here, I've been asked to create a guild website for a friend as he did not want to use one of the guild website creator tools, and wanted a custom design.

However one thing that has been asked for, is the ability to have any time a world of warcraft item name is mentioned, it converts to an item link (similar to that of "thottbot's")
    Now i'm pretty sure I would be able to do this if I could find a database of the items within the game, and then just use php to convert the string to a tooltip style.

So I guess the question there is.. Does anybody know of a database of the wow items i can utilize, or if blizz provide one themselves?

The other problem I have, is I have been asked to provide a "latest loot" window in the sidebar. Displaying who received what in the most recent raid the guild has undergone. But once again have come up with nothing whilst searching around for a source for this information. (They dont want to have to manually input each item after each raid)

Any idea where I can pull some of this info from?  I'm fairly confident that if I can find the info, I can convert it to the form I desire.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about code you have written

Comment: @JohnConde I disagree. Its about *code* hes trying to write and hes asking about existing facilities from WoW to support his code. There happens to be an answer that is an API designed exactly for people like him. Shouldnt have to know to phrase "yadda yadda" just to ask a question here. People who live here should know how to interpret that.

Comment: @JohnConde This is not off-topic. This is not a php question per se and is a common programming question for the WoW community. See above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Blizzard has a WoW API that appears to give you the information you want: http://blizzard.github.io/api-wow-docs/

Comment: Brilliant! I had been using a third party API up until now. Can't believe I had overlooked the blizzard one...
Thank you so much, exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 0):

It's been years since I played Blizzard games, but I believe all the data you are looking for is in the game's .mpq file.  Search "blizzard mpq extractor" for ways to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is probably where you really want to start.

Blizzard Community Platform API:
http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/2626217/

This is an active effort to support third party websites for WoW, with content and realtime APIs. Is probably easier than trying to manage the thousands of content items in the MPQs.